# Maven(pom.xml) do not run a plugin during deploy/install phase

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

If I have a pom.xml with the following code:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>something</groupId>
        <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugins>
 </build>
```

When I run `mvn clean package`, I want to run that plugin(which actually runs).

but

If I run `mvn clean deploy`, given phase `package` is previous to phase `deploy` is gonna run either(which I don't want to).

**Is there any way to not run this plugin during deploy?**

By the way: I cannot modify the `mvn` command executed, I need to do this inside the `pom.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know to selectively enable a plugin is through Maven profile:

```
<project ...>
...

<build>
...
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>someprofile</id>
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>something</groupId>
                <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

</project>
```

You would then run `mvn package -Psomeprofile` to run the plugin, or `mvn deploy` to not run it.

There are additional ways to [automatically activate a profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#how-can-a-profile-be-triggered-how-does-this-vary-according-to-t). You will have to read the docs to see if any of those apply to you.